# Newton-Raphson method for the function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, newton-raphson, linear-approximation

So, I need to invert the following function

[image]
and express alpha 2 in terms of D, where both t and alpha 1 are constant.
Someone suggested the Newton-Raphson method, and here's what I've done so far

[image]
[image]

Okay, but what do I do now? Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: may be that a judicious choice of trigonometric substitution could help here? Thinking something like $\sec{x} = \sqrt{\tan^2{x} + 1}$

Comment: It seems to me that the Newton-Raphson method would only be useful if you have numerical values for the other parameters. The method is not going to give you a solution of $\alpha_2$ expressed in terms of other variables, but only a numerical value given values for the other parameters and an accuracy bound.